# groovy.sql.Sql.asSql In Groovy SQL please do not use quotes around dynamic expressions

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a query in Grails like this:

```
 def strQuery = """select date_trunc('${type}', range) as range, sum(total_count) as total_count from connector_message_statistic  
                where range >= '${startDate}' and range < '${endDate}'
                group by date_trunc('${type}', range)                
            order by 1 asc;"""
```

I have this warning in the catalina log:

```
groovy.sql.Sql.asSql In Groovy SQL please do not use quotes around dynamic expressions (which start with $) as this means we cannot use a JDBC PreparedStatement and so is a security hole. Groovy has worked around your mistake but the security hole is still there. The expression so far is: select date_trunc('?', range) as range, is_internal,direction, sum(total_count) as total_count, sum(total_message_size) as total_message_size
```

How should I get rid of it? The problem is the dynamic date_trunc parameter.
When I try something like this:

```
select date_trunc(:type, range) ....... group by date_trunc(:type, range)
sql.eachRow(strQuery, type: type)
```

Then I get this exception:

```
ERROR: column "connector_message_statistic.range" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 23
```

How can I rewrite such a query to avoid these warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from injecteer helped me, this code is working now:

```
  strQuery = """select date_trunc(:type, range) as rangenew, is_internal,direction, sum(total_count) as total_count, sum(total_message_size) as total_message_size 
                    from connector_message_statistic 
                    where range >= :startDate::timestamp and range < :endDate::timestamp 
                    group by rangenew, is_internal,direction
                    order by 1 asc;"""
    sql.eachRow(strQuery, [type: type, startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate]
```

I renamed the fieldname in date_trunc and added the field in the group by clause

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should be using the parametrized query instead of such like yours. This way the Hibernate or Groovy SQL can properly box the parameters according to their types.

I'd put the query like so:

```
def result = SomeDomain.executeQuery( 'select date_trunc(:type, range) as range, sum(total_count) as total_count from connector_message_statistic  
           where range >= :startDate and range < :endDate
           group by date_trunc( :type, range)                
           order by 1 asc", [ type:type, startDate:startDate, endDate:endDate ] )
```

You could also use `positional` params:

```
def result = SomeDomain.executeQuery( 'select date_trunc(?, range) as range, sum(total_count) as total_count from connector_message_statistic  
           where range >= ? and range < ?
           group by date_trunc( ?, range)                
           order by 1 asc", [ type, startDate, endDate, type ] )
```

Comment: It looks like those queries will include the literals `'type'`, `'startDate'`, `'endDate'` etc. as the criteria values, instead of the values of variables with those names being used to generate the criteria.  Is that the intent?

Comment: The answer has been updated since my previous comment.  I haven't run the code, but it looks like it is probably better now.  Thanks!

Comment: When I try this : strQuery = """select date_trunc(:type, range) as range, is_internal,direction, sum(total_count) as total_count, sum(total_message_size) as total_message_size 
                        from connector_message_statistic 
                        where range >= '${startDate}' and range < '${endDate}' 
                        group by date_trunc(:type, range), is_internal,direction
                        order by 1 asc;"""
        sql.eachRow(strQuery, [type: type])

Comment: I get the exception: column "connector_message_statistic.range" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: try renaming the `range` alias here `date_trunc(:type, range) as range` to something esle

Comment: Yes, this works!! select date_trunc(:type, range) as rangenew ..... group by rangenew